# Regular expression with asterisk quantifier

Tags: javascript, regex

This [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) states this about the asterisk quantifier:

> Matches the preceding character 0 or more times.

It works in something like this:

```javascript
var regex = /<[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*>/;
var str = "<html>";
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

The result of the above is : `<html>`

But when tried on the following code to get all the "r"s in the string below, it only returns the first "r". Why is this?

```
var regex = /r*/;
var str = "rodriguez";
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

Why, in the first example does it cause "the preceding" character/token to be repeated "0 or more times" but not in the second example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var regex = /r*/;
var str = "rodriguez";
```

The regex engine will first try to match `r` in `rodriguez` from left to right and since there is a match, it consumes this match.

The regex engine then tries to match another `r`, but the next character is `o`, so it stops there.

Without the global flag `g` (used as so `var regex = /r*/g;`), the regex engine will stop looking for more matches once the regex is satisfied.

Try using:

```
var regex = /a*/;
var str = "cabbage";
```

The match will be an empty string, despite having `a`s in the string! This is because at first, the regex engine tries to find `a` in `cabbage` from left to right, but the first character is `c`. Since this doesn't match, the regex tries to match 0 times. The regex is thus satisfied and the matching ends here.

It might be worth pointing out that `*` alone is greedy, which means it will first try to match as many as possible (the 'or more' part from the description) before trying to match 0 times.

To get all `r` from `rodriguez`, you will need the global flag as mentioned earlier:

```
var regex = /r*/g;
var str = "rodriguez";
```

You'll get all the `r`, plus all the empty strings inside, since `*` also matches 'nothing'.

Comment: Thanks I understand the logic behind this now.

Answer (score 1):

Use global switch to match 1 or more r anywhere in the string:

```
var regex = /r+/g;
```

In your other regex:

```
var regex = /<[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*>/;
```

You're matching literal `<` followed by a letter followed by 0 or more letter or digits and it will perfectly match `<html>`

But if you have input as `<foo>:<bar>:<abc>` then it will just match `<foo>` not other segments. To match all segments you need to use `/<[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*>/g` with global switch.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the "why" apart from the "how" that you provided.

Comment: `*` means _"keep matching until it is not true"_, where as the `g`lobal flag means _"after we've found a match, start looking for a second match, then a third, etc"_

Comment: @robertrocha: check my updated answer for explanation.

Comment: When [a-z]* is used on "rodriguez" it returns the whole string. Even though there are several repetitions of "r". Does this mean that after the * has found its first match does the engine reset itself to "a" and search on through again until it arrives at "z" against the next character?

Comment: When you use `[a-z]*` it means 0 or more of **any** character in the range of a to z. Which will match `abcde` in  `abcde-123` but `/^r*/` means 0 or more of only letter `r`. If input is `rrrrr-987` It will match `rrrrr` but not in `rarbrcrdr-987` because `r` letters are not contiguous.