# how to find all matches with regex in elm

Tags: regex, elm

I am trying to find all matches in a string with Regex

`Regex.find Regex.All (Regex.regex "a*") "aabkdjfaab"`

> [{ match = "aa", submatches = [], index = 0, number = 1 }] : List Regex.Match

I would expect there be two matches

> [{ match = "aa", submatches = [], index = 0, number = 1 }, { match == "aa", submatches = [], index = 9, number = 1 }] : List Regex.Match

however this works if I do

`Regex.find Regex.All (Regex.regex "aa") "aabkdjfaab"`

what am i missing?

Comment: This isn't cause by Elm. The seemingly quirky behavior occurs in javascript too (try `/a*/g.exec("aabkdjfaab")`). Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20922143/regular-expression-with-asterisk-quantifier) can shed some light. Note that `a*` matches the empty string, and you can see all the empty string matches in javascript with `"aabkdjfaab".match(/a*/g)`.

Comment: You probably want `a+` and not `a*`. `a+` gives me `[{ match = "aa", submatches = [], index = 0, number = 1 },{ match = "aa", submatches = [], index = 7, number = 2 }]`.